# Separated wood 15 minutes after starting glue up, reapplied glue, and re-clamped, will the joint fail?

Tags: glue

I'm making an end-grain cutting board.

While gluing my (18) strips of wood together, I dry fit the pieces, glued them, and clamped them.

As I was finishing tightening the clamps, I noticed that the boards had all tilted slightly relative to each other, creating a slight saw-tooth pattern along their edges. I decided to unclamp, and attempt to straighten the pieces.

It was difficult to loosen the pieces at this point, and I gave up after separating just two pieces (one joint). I wiped some of glue off, which felt tacky at this point, and applied plenty of new glue, and reset and clamped everything.

It had been between 10 and 15 minutes between when I initially applied the glue, and when I reapplied and re-clamped.

I'm planning on cutting to re-square it and remove the tilt, but I'm worried that the joint I separated and re-glued won't form a strong bond. Is this something I need to be concerned with?

I was using Titebond III wood glue.

Comment: The real question, once you've followed Volfram's suggestion is to determine if it is strong _enough_ for your purposes. Remember, a cutting board isn't holding up your roof. If it fails in 10 years, it'll certainly be annoying, but not fatal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Older glue in a joint is definitely not ideal, but this might have worked OK. It's possible the key factor in success here is the clamp pressure you applied, since PVA glues of all types require *very* high clamp pressures to achieve the strongest bond (varying somewhat species to species). Deffo test if possible, but you might be able to guess at the relative strengths of the separated joint versus the others by seeing if there's a visible difference in glue-line thickness — thicker is always weaker (hence why high clamp pressure is the order of the day with PVAs).

Comment: Hi OP, did you abandon this Q?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe good, maybe weak. Impossible to say in theory, you must check to be sure.

Once you make offcut test it, if wood can separate on glue line joint was weak. If wood breaks joint is strong.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like the best way to test it, and the joint did end up being strong enough.